# select2- trigger reset doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, jquery-select2, reset

I'm using select to in my app for selecting option from the dropdown.
The select2 is implemented on input list I have in a form
I want to reset all the form when the user click on cancel.

I try

```
 $(idOfTheForm).trigger(reset)
```

but the selecting results which display in the inputs are not reset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this code for the reset

```
$("#select_id").select2("val", "");
```